# Anylogic: Queue TimeOut blocks flow

Tags: queue, timeout, anylogic, pull, discrete

I have a pretty simple Anylogic DE model where POs are launched regularly, and a certain amount of material gets to the incoming Queue in one shot (See Sample Picture below). Then the Manufacturing process starts using that material at a regular rate, but I want to check if the material in the queue gets outdated, so I'm using the TimeOut option of that queue, in order to scrap the outdated material (older than 40wks).

The problem is that every time that some material gets scrapped through this Timeout exit, the downstream Manufacturing process "stops" pulling more material, instead of continuing, and it does not get restarted until a new batch of material gets received into the Queue.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot in advance!!
Kindest regards

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: Isn't it just the case that at time 40wk all the material in the queue get discarded and then there is nothing left? What is your condition for the queue timeout?

Comment: Thanks Jaco! I'm afraid this is not the case. If you see the chart in the picture, the yellow line shows the queue size, and it does not go all the way down to 0, but it remains constant. Hence there's still some material that could (and should) get processed by the Delay Block. The condition for the queue timeout is just a constant amount of time (40wks)

Comment: Is there any way I could be uploading and sharing the model for your review?

Comment: uploaded anywhere and just share the link (dropbox, wetransfer, etc etc etc)

Comment: Thanks Felipe! Link below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lWL401JbINQkWLE1IUv37B3g81fj8zlT/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @ecarran this looks like an internal bug to me... do you mind sending your model to AnyLogic support.. I can't see anything wrong. Also cant seem to get the delay to start working again without injecting a new agent into the queue - very peculiar

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jaco-BenVosloo, I'll share it with Anylogic Support. I'll leave this topic open, just in case someone else can share some thoughts, or to keep you all up-to-date on Anylogic's reponse at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is interesting because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what you're doing. So even though what you are doing seems to be correct, I will provide you with a workaround. Instead of the ***Queue*** block, use a ***Wait*** block. You can assign a timeout and link the timeout port just like you did for the queue (seem image at the end of the answer).

In the `On Enter` field of the wait block (which I will assume is named `Fridge`), write the following code:

```
if( MFG.size() < MFG.capacity ) {
self.free(agent);
}
```

In the `On Enter` of MFG block write the following:

```
if( self.size() < self.capacity && Fridge.size() > 0 ) {
    Fridge.free(Fridge.get(0));
    }
```

And finally, in the `On Exit` of your MFG block write the following:

```
if( Fridge.size() > 0 ) {
    Fridge.free(Fridge.get(0));
}
```

What we are doing in the above, is we are manually pushing the agents. Each time an agent is processed, the model checks if there is capacity to send more, if yes, a new agent is sent.

I know this is an unpleasant workaround, but it provides you with a solution until AnyLogic support can figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @EmileZankoul, your code looks really interesting and it works fine, so this helps in fixing the issue (at least temporarily). I'm afraid I cannot reach Anylogic's Support Team, as I'm using just a Personal Learning Edition, so if someone else could let them know about this, that's really appreciated. Thanks again and kind regards